# How to use the trained network for prediction using new input

Tags: matlab, neural-network

My Input is:

```
x=[13000 x 7]:  (13000 rows and 7 columns)
and My Target is t=[13000 x 2]:
```

This is the t matrix  data Foramt:

```
0     1     1     1     0  ...
1     0     0     0     1  ...
```

The network was trained using the code provided by MATLAB  and The network was trained and worked fine.
net = train(net,x,t);

**MY QUESTION:**
I have new inputs (xnew) that I want to predict the output based on the trained network.
The new inputs are not part of the trained network.
I just want to predict the outcome from the new set of inputs.
So i used  tnew=net(xnew):
but the output of the new data (xnew) is as follows:

```
0.6951    0.8703    0.8087    0.8034    0.9182    ...
0.3049    0.1297    0.1913    0.1966    0.0818    ...
```

According to the calculations, but the output should be 0 or 1, please advise what to do.

Comment: You should consider learning a bit more about the theory and concepts underlying neural networks, e.g. through the documentation of the code you use or with any machine learning textbook.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the probability of your code. You should convert the probabilities to predictions. If you specify a threshold and use a simple if method (for ex. if a > threshold it will return 1, else 0) may be it can help you.